# ffmpeg4android for every processor type?

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg, processors

There is a issue with ffmpeg4android, it goes for armeabi-v7a only, is there an option to make it work for x86, x86_64 and arm64-v8a? Litteraly, no idea what to do, maybe there is an option to user arm64-v8a backwards compability with armeabi-v7a?

Comment: Have you got the solution to this?

Comment: @NithisKumar there is no solution from my side, you can try to contact lib developers for more info, maybe they will help you with it.